# Can I say "good in school"?

Tags: vocabulary

When I want to talk about a successful student, can I describe him/her as follows?

- She's very good in school. (or at school?)
- She's good at her lessons (or she's good in her studies?)
- She's good in her classes.

I appreciate your answers.

Comment: "She is good in school" could mean the opposite of "naughty".  She is the one who sits in the front row and listens to the teacher, while the others are passing notes and carving their initials into the desks.

Comment: @Cascabel I'm not sure the dupe really covered the duped (no criticism of yourself). And I feel the duped was probably closed too swiftly. However, 'which preposition with which adjective' questions / answers have doubtless covered this particular example already somewhere on ELU. // '_Good at_ her lessons' shows much more cohesiveness than '_good_ in school'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't actually VTC as a dupe...I voted as "lack of research". I was kind of hoping the OP would do the minimum of research, as there are no doubt many like this on the site.